# Postgresql Loop with Begin End block inside it is interrupted when the exception is thrown, while it is intercepted; loop should run until the end

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-function

I have a function like that:

```
create or replace function produciblepwforregulation(now date, timerange integer, devicename character varying) returns void
    language plpgsql
as $$
BEGIN
    FOR t IN 1..timeRange BY 1
        LOOP
            BEGIN
            insert into values
            (value, time, devicename)
            values (    2200 +
                        600 *
                                round(abs(sin(((t) * 0.042))) + 0.1) *
                                (sin(sin(((t) * 2 / 2.0 / 2.155172413793103 * PI()))) /
                                abs(sin(sin(((t) * 2 / 2.0 / 2.155172413793103 * PI()))))) *
                                (3 - exp(-12.5 + floor((t) * 2 / 2.0 / 2.155172413793103) * 2.155172413793103 * PI() * 2 * round(abs(sin(((t) * 0.042))) + 0.1) - ((t) * 2 * PI())))
                        +
                        600 *
                                abs(round(abs(sin(((t) * 0.042))) + 0.1) - 1) *
                                (sin(sin(((t) / 2.0 / 4.310344827586207 * PI()))) /
                                abs(sin(sin(((t) / 2.0 / 4.310344827586207 * PI()))))) *
                                (3 - exp(-25.5 + floor((t) / 2.0 / 4.310344827586207) * 4.310344827586207 * PI() * 2 * abs(round(abs(sin(((t) * 0.042))) + 0.1) - 1) - ((t) * PI())))
                        + 50 * sin(3 + (t) * 0.092) + 350 * sin(3 + (t) * 0.012),
                    now + t * INTERVAL '1 second' - 1 * INTERVAL '1 milliseconds',
                    devicename);             
              EXCEPTION WHEN others THEN NULL;  -- <- here I expect the funtion will just go ahead with its loop 
              END;  
        END LOOP;        
END

$$;

alter function produciblepwforregulation(date, integer, varchar) owner to postgres;
```

When the function is called, the timerange passed as the parameter in order to expect 86400 steps

```
  select produciblepwforregulation('2020-11-18', 86400, '1');
```

However, the execution stops on 194 steps, possibly facing some exception (the function inside is capable for underflow exception). My expectation that the exception just stops the Begin-End block inside the Loop and thus we just switch to another t value in the loop, and the execution shouldn't stop. But it is actually stops and never overcome the t value in the loop that causes the problem.

PS. I know that it is very unoptimized, but I really need got that to be executed as a part of postgresql function.

PPS. I see absolutely no error message here when I call the function execution, so the error (that's according to my expectation is an error) is silent for me:

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add the exact error message.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe the function is executed with silent error and I just see that it produces less data then expected. So I see no error, it returns empty value as expected, but doesn't do the whole expected job.

Comment: Then all `INSERT`s cause an error, and you enter the `EXCEPTION` clause every time. You'll have to debug that error, perhaps by *not* ignoring the error.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe when it not suppressed, it got `value out of range: underflow`, so is there a type cast to avoid it?

Comment: That means you called a numerical function or did a conversion from `double precision` to `real` that caused an underflow. You'll have to debug your formula.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe after debugging the formula where I tried even to add `::double precision` after each calculated value inside the exp function, I'm still getting underflow. also, debugging or `EXPLAIN` doesn't point me the types that are used under the hood.

Comment: Debugging a complicated formula is best done by first trying with parts of the formula. See that you reproduce the error with just a simple `SELECT` using constant numbers. This is hardly the forum to give you a course in basic debugging...